# How can we use Google Maps API to represent indoor building with multiple floors

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am planning to build a map(multiple floors) in android. 
How can we use Google Maps API to represent indoor building with multiple floors.
Can you please provide or point an example to represent building with multiple floors?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out http://indoo.rs/ if you want to create your own indoor building maps.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is enabled by default in Google Maps. You can test it by opening the map at these coordinates for example 51.510666,-0.117043 and zoom in a lot.

There is no support to add custom buildings with indoor maps. All you can do is put markers and ground overlays. The solution would be to cycle some ground overlays depending on the zoom level.